# Collections use in foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net, foreach

I am iterating through a collection in a foreach loop and was wondering.
When this gets executed by the .NET runtime

```
foreach (object obj in myDict.Values) {
    //... do something
}
```

Does the myDict.Values get invoked for every loop or is it called only once?

Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just once. It's roughly equivalent to:

```
using (IEnumerator<Foo> iterator = myDict.Values.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (iterator.MoveNext())
    {
        object obj = iterator.Current;
        // Body
    }
}
```

See section 8.8.4 of the C# 4 spec for more information. In particular, details about the inferred iteration element type, disposal, and how the C# compiler handles `foreach` loops over types which don't implement `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: I bet you know the section by heart :)

Comment: Noble of you to quote the C# Spec instead of C# in depth, 2nd Ed :)

Answer (score 6):

Short answer:  it is only called once.

Comment: To expound: foreach grabs the Enumerator (via the IEnumerable interface on your collection) and calls Next() each time through the loop.

Answer (score 2):

It gets called once and will generate an exception if the collection is modified.

Comment: Yes, good point.  If it is just a value in a class then this will not effect it but if items are added or removed from the collection this is a problem.